# Git, images and web development best practices

Tags: git, web-deployment

I've looked around a bit but haven't found a definitive answer to this.

Presently I like to develop new web site features (in Drupal but I think this is relevant to other web development projects) where all the code and supporting images are wrapped up into a branch that is dedicated to the particular feature.  This is so I can easily deploy the work to staging environments for review before deployment to the production environment.  From various sources I've read it seems like putting images into the repository is generally not advisable yet I don't really see an alternative that doesn't involve a lot of extra legwork. Basically my current philosophy is everything that's involved in the front-end gets committed and resources like PDFs and other binaries that are not involved with the actual operation of the site are maintained in an ignored directory, which I sync as needed with rsync or FTP.

Am I missing some feature of Git that would solve this or is this just what web developers that use Git do - accept that images get maintained in the repository?

Related to this but sort of a different question: when I commit an image but then subsequently delete it in a future commit is its bulk still an irreversible part of the repository's history?

Thanks

Comment: I found this exchange that pretty much answers my question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

So Git is a version control system that does snapshots of changed files.

You can definitely put images into your repository, and use Git to track it (with `git add`), as well as PDFs and other shorts of binaries. Git will then keep track if any changes to those files are made. For example, you edited/resized an image. It will have to recommit the entire image, as it is seen as a binary file, Git will definitely make a new snapshot of the file, and not reference to the previous file, because it has changed.

**What the difference** between commiting code changes and changes with binary/image files is that you can actually see what differences there were in the code, but not in the binary files.

If however you do not want version tracking of image files, adding them to a directory that is ignored by git is the way to go, as you mentioned, and you can keep things in sync with whatever utility you prefer.

However, in case it's not clear, I'd like to note that if there aren't any changes to your images/binary files between commits, no extra space is taken up as the snapshot made will simply refer to the previous file. i.e: Say you added a jpg file with size of 1MB, then did 4 commits after that without changing the file, all the 4 commits will reference the initial file you added, Git won't make 4 identical copies. So I don't see why you cannot use Git to maintain images in the repo, unless you explicitly don't want to do that for reasons such as if the changes made to the images are not important to you.

[Link to Git Manual on how commits/snapshots work](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)

**When I commit an image but then subsequently delete it in a future commit is its bulk still an irreversible part of the repository's history?**

Yes. If you added an image, then later deleted it in a future commit, the previous commits are not affected at all, so the image will still live in the repository's history. It's irreversible in a way that you cannot physically go in and delete the image. (Integrity of Git, also in the Git-Scm book I linked). you could however delete that commit by using the provided commands to remove it. In a nutshell, a future commit does not affect the historical commits, which is by design. Deleting the image in the future will only cause git to not track that image anymore in future commits.

I can't comment on best practices as I have limited knowledge on web dev and have no heard of any best practices, though. Hopefully I've shed some light on Git as an scm.

**Also**, check out GitHub if you haven't already, it's a great place to host your Git repository, they have free public repos and paid private ones. BitBucket is another option too! This way you wouldn't have to handle all the server side maintenance, that is if you are allowed to do that for your work.

Comment: Thank you for your write-up and answering my second question.  My main question is for the opinions of web developers on how they deal with images that are part of the web site since I've read several places that keeping images in the repository is generally bad practice.  I'm wondering if there is a feature or extension of Git that I should be using instead.